# How to get all users in telegram chat with telebot or requests lib in Python?

Tags: python, python-requests, telegram

I want to get list of all users in my channel/chat. People suggests using **telethon**, but i can't get started with telethone and want to use requests instead. Can u help me please?

I tried

```
import json 
import requests
URL = "https://api.telegram.org/bot{}/".format(TOKEN) 
url = URL + "getFullChat?chat_id={}".format(chat_id)
req = requests.get(url)
```

where **TOKEN** is my bot's id and **chat_id** is the chat, where I want to get the list from.

```
req.content
```

returns me

```
b'{"ok":false,"error_code":404,"description":"Not Found"}'
```

https://core.telegram.org/method/channels.getFullChannel

https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.getFullChat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem, here is the code

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient 

api_id = XXX # int
api_hash = 'XXX'
 
client = TelegramClient('session_name_choose_yourself', api_id, api_hash)
 
assert client.start()
 
if not client.is_user_authorized():
    client.send_code_request(bot_token)
 
entity=client.get_entity("@ChatUserName")
users = client.get_participants(entity)
print(len(users))
 
for i in users:
    print(i.id, i.username, i.first_name, i.last_name)
```

The session created will store the password and/or telephone number you need to add manually